# ggplot2: add RMSE values of two models to each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Using this data.frame

**DATA**

```
#import_data
df <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fdi26qy4ozs4xq/df_RMSE.csv?raw=1"))
```

and this script

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes( measured, simulated, col = indep_cumulative))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method ="lm", se = F)+
  facet_grid(drain~scenario)
```

I got this plot
[image]

I want to add `RMSE` for each of the two models (independent and accumulative; two values only) to the top left in each facet.

I tried

```
geom_text(data = df , aes(measured, simulated, label= RMSE))
```

It resulted in RMSE values being added to each point in the facets.

I will appreciate any help with adding the two RMSE values only to the top left of each facet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to plot two numbers per facet you need to do some data preparation to avoid text overlapping.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(label_vjust=if_else(indep_cumulative == "accumulative",
                             1, 2.2))
```

In your question you explicitly told `ggplot2` to add `label=RMSE` at points with `x=measured` and `y=simulated`. To add labels at top left corner you could use `x=-Inf` and `y=Inf`. So the code will look like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(measured, simulated, colour = indep_cumulative)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method ="lm", se = F) +
  geom_text(aes(x=-Inf, y=Inf, label=RMSE, vjust=label_vjust),
            hjust=0) +
  facet_grid(drain~scenario)
```

[image]

Comment: @aelwan `?sprintf` / `?paste` (you'll do better in R if you actually look some things up vs rely on others for quick answers)

Comment: @hrbrmstr
Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @aelwan perhaps lookup other aesthetic parameters for `geom_text()` like text justification and nudging

Comment: @evgeniC
Thanks. I added RMSE = value ton/ha/yr as below
`geom_text(aes(x=-Inf, y=Inf, label= paste("RMSE= ", RMSE, "ton/ha/yr"), vjust=label_vjust,
            hjust=0))`

Comment: @aelwan You're welcome. And yes, that is the way to add customized labels.